# how to modify this function so that it allows numbers also

Tags: jquery

I have this function which doesn't allow any special characters

Please let me know how to modify this function so that it allows numbers also ??

```
<input type="text" id="category"  onkeypress="return nospecialCharacters(event,this)"  class="m-wrap span12" placeholder="">


function nospecialCharacters(thi,dec)
{
    if (window.event) keycode = window.event.keyCode;
        else if (e) keycode = e.which;
        else return true;

   if (((keycode>=65) && (keycode<=90))||((keycode>=97) && (keycode<=122)) || keycode==32)
   {
        return true;
   }
   else
   {
        return false;
   }
}
```

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/z167ac64/

Comment: Allow the keyCodes you want http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/

Comment: I was seen your profile. Is better for you that accept answers, your rate is very low and people won't be glad to answer you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This work with the ASCII table code:

[image]

```
<input type="text" id="category"  onkeypress="return nospecialCharacters(event,this)"  class="m-wrap span12" placeholder="">


function nospecialCharacters(thi,dec)
{
    if (window.event) keycode = window.event.keyCode;
        else if (e) keycode = e.which;
        else return true;

   if (((keycode>=48) && (keycode<=57))||((keycode>=65) && (keycode<=90)) ||((keycode>=97) && (keycode<=122)) || keycode==32)
   {
        return true;
   }
   else
   {
        return false;
   }
}
```